# neostore.* file size after deleting millions node

Tags: neo4j

I use neo4j 1.9.4, i store 28M nodes, 267M properties and 157M relationships.

the neostore.* files :

-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  10961964959  7 fév 09:58 neostore.propertystore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   5185764606  7 fév 09:58 neostore.relationshipstore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   3550760192  7 fév 09:58 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel    249658236  7 fév 09:58 neostore.nodestore.db

I delete 26M nodes and the neostore.* is not reduce :

-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  10961964979  7 fév 10:20 neostore.propertystore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   5185764630  7 fév 10:20 neostore.relationshipstore.db
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel   3550760218  7 fév 10:20 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel    249658252  7 fév 10:20 neostore.nodestore.db

i remove all nodes from 'ticket' index, the lucene index /index/lucene/node/ticket folder is empty
when i count all tickets nodes i get 0 -> OK

why neostore.* file size is not reduce ?

here the delete code =

```
EndResult<Ticket> tickets = ticketRepository.findByDate(date); // by 1000
Iterator<Ticket> itTicket = tickets.iterator(); 

  while (itTicket.hasNext()) { 

 Ticket t = itTicket.next(); 
 Node n = neo4jTemplate.getGraphDatabase().getNodeById(t.getId()); 
 neo4jTemplate.getIndex("Ticket").remove(n); 

 Iterable<Relationship> relationships = n.getRelationships(); 

  for (Relationship relationship : relationships) { 

    relationship.delete(); 
 }
 n.delete(); 

 }
```

Can you help me ?
Charles
regards

Answer (score 1):

Actually the nodestore is not instantly compacted after you delete nodes. Instead if you create new nodes they will reclaim the previously deleted ares with in nodestore.